# The output of diff fails to render in with enabled LaTeX

Tags: python, sympy

I want to differentiate an expression as follows in `sympy`. I am using `jupyter qtconsole` with enabled latex:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
p0,nu,lamb,k,epsp, dp0 = symbols(r'p_0, nu, lambda, kappa, \delta\epsilon_p^p, \deltap_0')
test = Eq(epsp,((lamb-k)/nu)*dp0/p0)
p0expr = solve(test,p0)[0]
diff(p0expr, epsp)
diff(p0expr,k)
diff(p0expr,lamb)
```

I'd like to focus on the last three lines of code, lines 6, 7 and 8. Lines 7 and 8 output latex style output while line 6 does not. Why does line 6 not get output in latex?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the text output for `diff(p0expr, epsp)`,

```
-\deltap_0*(-kappa + lambda)/(\delta\epsilon_p^p**2*nu)
```

the problem is in squaring the variable you named `\delta\epsilon_p^p`.  (The other two derivatives don't have it squared.) If this square gets converted in LaTeX markup as

```
\delta\epsilon_p^p^2
```

the result is invalid LaTeX due to multiple superscripts. Suggestion: put curly braces around this symbol name,

```
symbols(r'p_0, nu, lambda, kappa, {\delta\epsilon_p^p}, \deltap_0')
```

which will prevent such interference between the name and the formula containing it.

Tested with http://live.sympy.org/ :

[image: live sympy]

Top output is from your version, bottom is with curly braces as above. It renders except for `\deltap` which of course is an undefined LaTeX command. Unless it's a custom thing you defined elsewhere, it's something that should be fixed with `{\delta}p_0`.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried your method and still the same problem. What's more none of them output latex if I curly-brace the last two symbols. My setup is really close to the one their main documentation recommends. Jupyter qtconsole is made by the same people who make Ipython and anaconda as far as I know